# Do I have to write media queries for every screen size my site could be viewed in, or is there an alternative?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am a junior front-end developer and have just started looking into responsive design.  While the thought of media queries excited me, what happens when you don’t have enough breakpoints?

For the most part you can assume someone has an iPhone or iPad, but what about other tablets and mobile phones and different Mac/PC screen sizes? It will be a crazy task to write media queries for each screen size.

So, is there another way to accomplish responsive design without media queries? Or have I misunderstood how media queries can be used?

Comment: No other way/ though you can check [this](http://www.dudamobile.com/) out

Comment: @mr.alien thanks! but how do i solve the issue of different screen sizes? Or is it just ideal to have 5-6 breakpoints and that's it?

Comment: That makes a complete mobile website, you can register there and take a demo, when a user visits, he will be redirected to m.domain.com, you can remove blocks, add gallery, add menus, add pages etc

Comment: Just using percentages can give you responsiveness without the media queries

Comment: Well, you need to use `em` or `%` value as well. For myself, i use media query when the text is to hard to read to remove some unusefull content and change the number of colum. i usually have arround 3 or 4 breakpoint: Widescreen; screen; tablet; phone.

Comment: If you write your stylesheet in relation to character size (likely using ems) rather than pixels, you don't need to worry about any particular screen size.  Like  Karl-André Gagnon said... don't think about any particular screen size, just focus on the content.

Answer (score 7):

I’m not sure what sort of alternative you’re looking for. “Responsive design” means “design that responds to its environment”. To do that, you need something that lets you say “if the environment is X, do Y”. That’s what media queries do.

> It will be a crazy task to write media queries for each screen size

It would be! That’s not the idea. The web doesn’t work like that. HTML and its layout system are designed, as far as possible, to be viewable on pretty much any device, running all sorts of different software (web browser, screen reader, braille display, search engine crawler, etc.).

For example: by default, block level elements take up as much horizontal space as is available. You don't need to write a media query for every possible screen size to get them to do that, they just do it.

Breakpoints for your layout should be based more on the content being laid out than on the sizes of different devices. There’s several good articles outlining the approach:

- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/01/logical-breakpoints-responsive-design/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/
- http://www.markboulton.co.uk/journal/theinbetween

If you’re writing new styles for each slightly different screen size, you’re probably doing it wrong.

You could look at the screen sizes of popular devices to inform your design decisions, but Wikipedia already lists those, and will continue to do so into the future as new devices come out.

It’s not easy to make a design that works in lots of different viewports, but that’s not because of how media queries work. It’s an inherently difficult task.

Answer (score 2):

Just choose a selection of breaks that's manageable for you (say 4) and then code to those with fluid design so that your content expands into the size until it gets to the next break and then it jumps up to the next layout.

For example, if you choose to have width breaks at 320, 480, 800 and 1024 you could put a min-width at 320 to stop the content going smaller should a smaller device (not sure what) come along. If a device with width of 640 comes along it uses the 480 break and centres or uses fluid (CSS with % based sizes rather than px) and so the content expands to fill the extra space available.

In this examples anything greater than 1024 (which is mostly desktops and the higher spec tablets / phone) will use the last break. In reality this is the one you'll see most of the time as you develop.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you give me some breakpoints that will work for most of the devices? Thanks!

Comment: Typically using a (min-device-width:X) and (max-device-width:Y). I tend to have [X:320,Y:480] [X:640,Y:800] [X:1024,Y:1280] and then anything bigger with the default. Depending on your design, you may not even need the last one (don't forget the Orientation versions)

Comment: @KPO: “Can you give me some breakpoints that will work for most of the devices?” No. Five years ago, no-one knew that iPad minis and Samsung Galaxy Notes and Microsoft Surfaces would be popular. (Maybe I’m stretching “popular with that last one.”) The web is worldwide — you never know what device someone will use to look at it. It’s better to define the breakpoints for a design based on the design’s content. See e.g. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

Comment: In another five years, folks could be viewing our websites on 4K TVs, wall-sized iPads, or — if we think really outside of the box — on a popular device made by Blackberry. The challenge with web design is designing something that doesn’t break when the attributes of the hardware and software it’s being viewed on change.

Comment: True, but hopefully there will have been at least one design refresh by then :)

Comment: @CodeUniquely: very true. I think it’s fair to say that a design that doesn’t break in new environments is better though.

Answer (score 0):

We use Adapt.js on our project and it has worked out really nice for us.  We have four breakpoints:  mobile, tablet, notebook, and desktop.

We opted against media queries because we have to support IE8 and didn't want to mess with polyfills for CSS3 features.  Check it out.

http://adapt.960.gs/

Comment: You support IE 8 on mobile and tablet?